# Installing IE8 with Winetricks

Tags: wine, winetricks

I have been trying to install Internet Explorer 8 via Winetricks on the default `wine-prefix` but I'm getting an error after the unpack process, saying my configuration is `64-bits` and Internet Explorer 8 doesn't support it.

My question is, can I change the `wine-prefix` configuration? Since I have a game installed on it that the update took a really long time. I also tried using POL installed via software center and I get same error

I am using Xubuntu 12.10, and `wine 1.6RC`.

Comment: Why don't you just run firefox or chrome?

Comment: Most likely he's a poor webdeveloper who still needs to support IE8...

Comment: i use chromium but i need ie8 installed in the winprefix for a bug in-game. without it i have no icons

Answer (score 3):

To do it without PlayOnLinux (or POL for short) using normal Wine you should first, after doing a backup of anything you have installed inside the Wine folder (.wine):

```
rm -fr ~/.wine
export WINEARCH=win32
export WINEPREFIX="/home/$USER/.wine"
winecfg
```

This will start from scratch and set your Wine environment to 32 Bit. After opening `winecfg`, it will create the needed files and variables for the environment so you can install or copy anything you need to it again and it will work as 32 bit.

Comment: This doesn't install IE8. It appears that Microsoft has removed all IE versions from their public download site, so running `winetricks ie8` no longer works, regardless.

Comment: @Cerin you do know you are down voting an answer that worked 3.5 years ago? Which was verified by me at the time and after a year later. So pretty much you are down voting without any possibility of fixing the answer since the issue is created by Microsoft itself and not the question or the answers mentioned here.

Comment: And furthermore, if you have a current version of Winetricks, you can still install IE6, IE7, or IE8 in a 32-bit wineprefix.  I did it just a couple days ago -- about a year after the above downvote dispute.  There's a question around about how to be sure you have a current Winetricks, BTW.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. Solved this using [POL](https://www.playonlinux.com). Created a new 32 bits prefix, installed IE8 in there and then just copy-paste the game folder from wine.

Comment: What's POL? Glad to hear you're able to solve this.

Comment: @ChrisK It stands for Play On Linux according to Luis' answer. :)

Comment: Could you describe your solution a bit more? Like, where the wine folders are and how you managed to sync the game and ie8 into the same folder. Would help me with League of Legends

Comment: My POL gives me an error (it can't download the file....)